# Recuperating original term doc-id in sci-kit tfidf Vectorizer

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am using `tdidf vectorizer` in `sci-kit learn` in order to calculate td-idf values for the reviews of different movies. I have successfully implented the code but now I am trying to refine it to optimize the output. That being said, I would like to include in my output `CSV` information regarding the original `movie` or document that each term pertains too.

To solve this problem, I have already looked [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304191/get-the-document-name-in-scikit-learn-tf-idf-matrix) for inspiration without any success.

To do so, I am trying to recuperate the doc id or the row id in my dense `td-idf` matrix. It is very important that I know what document the terms that I am evaluating pertain too.

Currently, I have tried

```
counter = 0
corpus = []
key = {}
for id, movie in sorted(movies.iteritems(), key=lambda t: int(t[0])):
    corpus.append(movie)
    key[id] = counter
    counter+=1

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1), min_df = 0)
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(corpus)
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names()

def get_doc_row(docid):
    rowid = key[docid]
    row = tf[rowid,:]
    return row
```

when building my output as follows I am not sure how to associate the `row` to the `word` in order to have a proper identifier to the `movie` in my `CSV`:

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"])

    word_list = "words.txt"
    word_dict = {}
    with open(word_list) as f:
        for line in f:
            depurated_line = line.rstrip()
            (key, val) = depurated_line.split("\t")
            word_dict[key] = val

    doc_id = 0
    for doc in tfidf_matrix.todense():
        word_id = 0
        for score in doc.tolist()[0]:
            if score > 0:
                word = feature_names[word_id].encode("utf-8")
                wordPosish = row(word)
                print wordPosish
                if word in word_dict:
                    scoreWeight = score * 100
                    writer.writerow([doc_id+1, word.decode("utf-8"), scoreWeight, word_dict[word]])
            word_id +=1
        doc_id +=1
```

Currently, the order of the `doc_id` that I have does not correspond to the order that the documents are inputted into the system, which is why it is important that I find a way to somehow recuperate this information to included it in the output.

Is there a specific place where I should include the `row` defined above in order to recuperate the specific `doc` that the word originally pertained too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem by creating another dictionary that associates the docID to text before transforming that data to a matrix.

Then, I was able to associate in my output an individual word to its original doc.

This is the code that I implemented, I am still running tests, but it seems to have solved the problem.

```
idTracker = {}
idCounter = 1
for id, movie in movies.iteritems():
    corpus.append(movie)
    idTracker[idCounter] = id
    idCounter +=1
```